# how to stub specific IDs only in cucumber test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

Very new to Ruby and cucumber, and i've got a controller that accepts an ID. Basically a rest API, so the client would call /cows/1234 and /cows/777. That would then route to getFluffyCow and pass :id = 1234 or 777.

My initial attempt is as follows:

```
allow(getFluffyCow).to receive(:call).with(1234).and_return(mock_cow1)
allow(getFluffyCow).to receive(:call).with(777).and_return(mock_cow2)
```

but the response is returning nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The params will come through as strings so specify the ID's as strings when stubbing the :call method:

```
allow(getFluffyCow).to receive(:call).with('1234').and_return(mock_cow1)
allow(getFluffyCow).to receive(:call).with('777').and_return(mock_cow2)
```